# how to find average salary for each job role from a file in python

Tags: python, pandas, average

I am looking to write a `python` code to find the **average salary** for each type of job role

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are doing this as an exercise to learn how to code such things with Python? Then this approach which uses only the basic Python commands and types should be helpful:

```
# read file content
with open('emp_data.txt') as f:
    file_content = f.readlines()

# collect data
data = {}
for i, line in enumerate(file_content):
    if i == 0:
        # discard header
        continue
    index, person, age, job, salary, years = line.split(",")
    job = job.strip()
    salary = int(salary.strip())
    if not job in data:
        # create new empty list if this is the first time this job appears
        data[job] = []
    data[job].append(salary)

print("data =", data)

# calculate mean
mean = {}
for job in data:
    mean[job] = sum(data[job]) / len(data[job])

print("mean =", mean)
```

Which prints

```
data = {'Developer': [29000, 24000, 53000], 'Tester': [42000, 33000, 19000], 'Analyst': [21000, 44000, 28000], 'DevOps': [42000, 50000, 38000, 22000, 23000, 32000]}
mean = {'Developer': 35333.333333333336, 'Tester': 31333.333333333332, 'Analyst': 31000.0, 'DevOps': 34500.0}
```

If you want to use advanced modules, you should have a look at `numpy` or `pandas`.

Comment: it returns this error for me emp_no, emp_name, age, position, salary, years_emp = line.split(",")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 5)

Comment: yes i used the exact same code but the same error came back

Comment: Never mind. Yeah its working now. Thanks very much for the help

Answer (score 3):

> ***I am looking to write a python code to find the average salary for each type of position (Developer, DevOps, Analyst, Tester)***

---

You can use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this, i.e.:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('emp_data.txt', sep=", ", engine='python')
```

## [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)

```
print(df.groupby('POSITION').agg({'SALARY':'mean'}))
```

---

**Output:**

```
POSITION   SALARY            
Analyst    31000.000000
DevOps     34500.000000
Developer  35333.333333
Tester     31333.333333
```

---

## [median](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.median.html)

```
print(df.groupby('POSITION').agg({'SALARY':'median'}))
```

---

**Output:**

```
POSITION    SALARY
Analyst     28000
DevOps      35000
Developer   29000
Tester      33000
```

---

Notes:

- [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
- [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.median`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.median.html)
- [`median` vs `mean`](https://creativemaths.net/blog/median/)