# How to check for the existence of a row in an array, create it if it doesn't exist, or modify it if it does exist in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, average

Working from an unsorted array, I am trying to calculate the average value for a subset of a specific type.  That is, any given row has a type and a value where the type is an integer of some value (repeats within some range) and the value is a float. For example:

```
import numpy as np
np.data=array([[1,1.3],[2,2.2],[3,3.7],[4,5.1],[1,1.25],[2,2.3],[3,3.4]])
```

(A real world application of this problem might be, "find the average income by age for people in the list"; and then I'm going to plot income vs age)

How would I find the average of all values of type 1?  E.g. (np.data[0,1]+np.data[4,1])/2

I am currently trying to compile my average in a new array with my type, cumulative value, and a counter (then at the end I will divide the cumulative value by the counter to get the average).  So I define a new array and then try to check if there is an entry for the current type.  If there is, add to the cumulative value and iterate the counter, if not create a new row.  But how to check this?  This might not be the right structure (if instead of try?) and np.where returns an array.  Lots of problems, but I'm trying to keep it streamlined since my data array has millions of entries.

```
# avg = [type, cumulative val,counter]
# data = [type, value]
for i in xrange(1,len(data)):
  try:
    # find if there is already cumulative data for type of this data
    k = np.where(np.avg==data[i,0]) # this isn't right
    # if data is accumulating for this type, add and increment
    avg[k[0],1]+=data[i,1]
    avg[k[0],2]+=1
  except IndexError:
    # if there is no data for this type, add new row to array
    np.concatenate((avg,data[i]))
```

Edit:
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771596/how-to-find-average-salary-for-each-job-role-from-a-file-in-python) question and answer. So I put my "age" (type) as entries in a dictionary (if the type is not already present, it is added) looped over all entries resulting in list of values for each type:

```
data = {1: [0.9, 0.95, 0.85, 0.92,], 2: [1.8, 1.7, 1.9,1.83], ...]
```

Then I can loop over the data and average each list.  It seems to work pretty efficiently (no slow down on moderately large data sets).  Perhaps pandas would be better, but for now, I'll use this.

Comment: Have you considered using Pandas? You are likely to get much simpler (and probably faster) code with something like `pandas.groupby`.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem or for that matter, merely using a regular `list` would be much better

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My comment was on OP's end goal: "find the average income by age for people in the list"; and then ... plot income vs age. Pandas seems like a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771596/how-to-find-average-salary-for-each-job-role-from-a-file-in-python) question and answer. So I put my "age" (type) as entries in a dictionary (if the type is not already present, it is added) looped over all entries resulting in list of values for each type:

```
data = {1: [0.9, 0.95, 0.85, 0.92,], 2: [1.8, 1.7, 1.9,1.83], ...]
```

Then I can loop over the data and average each list. It seems to work pretty efficiently (no slow down on moderately large data sets). Perhaps pandas would be better, but for now, I'll use this.